# textscan undefined in Octave

Tags: compiler-errors, octave

```
fid = fopen('data/data_file.csv');
all_messages = textscan(fid, format, 'delimiter', ',');
```

Returns:

> error: 'textscan' undefined

How do you fix this?

Comment: `textscan(a,b,c,d) = 0` should work, but I doubt it is what you want. ;)

Comment: Does `fopen` have default parameters ? Seems like `fid` is damaged, try `fid = fopen("data/data_file.csv","r","ieee-l");`.

Comment: What version of Octave are you using? The `textscan` function was added in version 3.4.0, which was released in February 2011.

Comment: 3.2.4 so I guess that's why it didn't work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Core answer

The `textscan` function was added to Octave in version 3.4.0, which was released in February 2011. Your best option, then, is to install a newer version of Octave. If, for some reason, that is not an option you could try using `fscanf` (as suggested [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB#Notes_about_specific_functions)).

### History

The `textscan` function is not mentioned in the new function list in the [version 3.4 release news](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.4.html), but `textscan.m` is not present in the version 3.2.4 distribution.

It appears to have been added as a result of [this](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?31380) ticket (scroll to the bottom of the ticket), which was created as a result of [this](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/textscan-wanted-td3002808.html) request.

Comment: How? The "latest" version of the Windows installer is 3.2.4.

Comment: @BSeven From the [Downloading Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html) page there is a link to the [Octave Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/) for Windows binaries. On that page, currently, there is a link to a "Windows installer" that is for Octave 3.4.3. Readers from the future may see a different version.